# SQL How to select contents of a row directly above a row, and move both into a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write something to automatically clean up some travel data. See these as flights:

FLIGHTS:

```
ID      DocType     Name        Travel Date     Fare Paid
1       INV     Mrs G       13/03/2017      37.6
2       INV     Mrs G       13/03/2017      200
3       INV     Mr H        14/03/2017      60
4       INV     Mr H        15/03/2017      126
5       CRN     Mr H        15/03/2017      126
6       INV     Mr H        20/03/2017      126
7       INV     Mrs S       29/03/2017      110
8       INV     Mr J        26/03/2017      54
9       INV     Mr R        13/03/2017      200
10      INV     Miss C      27/03/2017      78.98
```

Sometimes people buy a flight and then get a refund. This shows up as two identical entries in the data, except that the refund is DocType 'CRN'. I need to be able to pull both the booking and the refund line out of the dataset.

I can do this for the CRN tagged rows. But how can I pull out rows that are immediately above the CRN rows? The ID of the related INV row will always have an ID that is directly and sequentially lower than the CRN row.

I have managed

```
INSERT INTO TRAVEL.REFUNDS (ID, DocType, Name, [Travel Date], [Fare Paid])
SELECT ID, DocType, Name, [Travel Date], [Fare Paid]
FROM TRAVEL.FLIGHTS
WHERE [DocType] = 'CRN';
GO
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Will every CRN row always have its related INV directly above it? If it is not always the case, then it will not help to "pull out rows that are immediately above the CRN rows".    If it will always appear directly above... is it as a result an ORDER BY clause? If so, what do you order by?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've made the dataset clearer in response. The related INV will always be directly above the CRN row because this is how the data are supplied. I immediately upload into SQL and assign an ID (primary key), which is now in the dataset. I have thought about an order by, but can't work out how to communicate that within the INSERT INTO instructions.

Comment: Given that rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets, please define 'above'. And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The related INV has an ID that is sequentially, and directly, before ('above') the CRN row ID (I've made this clearer in the post). and, you are welcome to not provide anything at all. Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 0):

This is for `SELECT` purposes, not sure if you wanted that or `INSERT` or `DELETE`, but hopefully it's easily reworkable to those, plus it's good to check before modifying, right?

What I'm doing is, I'm using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)/[LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) to add one new column, which is mostly a copy of some other <strike>row</strike> column, although shifted one row up or down. With that, you'll have each row containing everything needed to decide what to do with it, which will be done in the higher query that targets the lower query's results.

```
-- Making an MCVE, first time I know its name though.
DECLARE @Flights TABLE (ID int, DocType char(3))
INSERT INTO @Flights VALUES
    ( 1, 'INV')
  , ( 2, 'INV')
  , ( 3, 'INV') -- Should not show up.
  , ( 4, 'CRN') -- Should not show up.
  , ( 5, 'INV')
  , ( 6, 'INV')
  , ( 7, 'INV')
  , ( 8, 'INV')
  , ( 9, 'INV')
  , (10, 'INV') -- Should not show up.
  , (11, 'CRN') -- Should not show up.

-- Querying via LEAD(), with 1 level nesting (or subquerying, I dunno which is which).
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID
         , DocType AS DocTypeThis
         , LEAD(DocType) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS DocTypeOther -- Seems like the choice of ASC/DESC reverses LAG/LEAD behaviours into each other, although not sure.
    FROM @Flights
) AS T
WHERE (DocTypeOther IS NULL AND DocTypeThis = 'INV') -- Special treatment for last row (for other implementations, might be first row).
   OR DocTypeThis = DocTypeOther -- This is the core of filtering, this fails only when the row is a 'CRN', or is superceded directly by a 'CRN'.
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation. I haven't been able to translate this for my table yet but will keep trying as I've never used LAG before and want to get the hang of it

Comment: @JER, you're welcome, FYI there were a few mistakes in code and text, I corrected those and did some rephrasing, it's all under #4 in edit history.

Answer (score 0):

using `exists()`:

```
select *
from t 
where DocType = 'CRN' 
   or exists (
    select 1
    from t i
    where i.DocType='CRN'
      and i.id-1 = t.id
)
```

or a `left join`

```
select t.*
from t
  left join t i
    on i.id-1 = t.id 
where t.DocType = 'CRN' 
   or i.DocType = 'CRN'
```

rextester demo: [rextester.com/MSGGX10058](http://rextester.com/MSGGX10058)

returns:

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
| ID | DocType |  Name  | TravelDate | FarePaid |
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
|  4 | INV     | Mr H   | 15.03.2017 | 126.00   |
|  5 | CRN     | Mr H   | 15.03.2017 | 126.00   |
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
```

---

using `not exists()` for the opposite result set:

```
select *
from t
where DocType = 'INV'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from t i
    where i.DocType='CRN'
      and i.id-1 = t.id
)
```

returns:

```
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
| ID | DocType |  Name  | TravelDate | FarePaid |
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
|  1 | INV     | Mrs G  | 13.03.2017 | 37.60    |
|  2 | INV     | Mrs G  | 13.03.2017 | 200.00   |
|  3 | INV     | Mr H   | 14.03.2017 | 60.00    |
|  6 | INV     | Mr H   | 20.03.2017 | 126.00   |
|  7 | INV     | Mrs S  | 29.03.2017 | 110.00   |
|  8 | INV     | Mr J   | 26.03.2017 | 54.00    |
|  9 | INV     | Mr R   | 13.03.2017 | 200.00   |
| 10 | INV     | Miss C | 27.03.2017 | 78.98    |
+----+---------+--------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I've tested this and it works.